# How to decode examples in Tensorflow 2 (porting from 1.12)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have the following method which is supposed to decode samples from serialized `TFRecordDataset`:

```py
def decode_example(self, serialized_example):
    """Return a dict of Tensors from a serialized tensorflow.Example."""
    data_fields, data_items_to_decoders = self.example_reading_spec()
    # Necessary to rejoin examples in the correct order with the Cloud ML Engine
    # batch prediction API.
    data_fields['batch_prediction_key'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, 0)
    if data_items_to_decoders is None:
        data_items_to_decoders = {
            field: tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder.Tensor(field)
            for field in data_fields
        }

    decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder.TFExampleDecoder(data_fields, data_items_to_decoders)

    decode_items = list(sorted(data_items_to_decoders))
    decoded = decoder.decode(serialized_example, items=decode_items)
    return dict(zip(decode_items, decoded))
```

However, this does not work under Tensorflow 2.

`tf.contrib` does not exist anymore and I do not find anything I can use to decode these examples.

I cannot even find the [`TFExampleDecoder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/api_docs/python/tfdv/TFExampleDecoder)  after installing `tensorflow-data-validation`.

Any idea what's wrong there and/or how I can decode my examples?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: @physicist I posted an answer how I made it work. hth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work using `tf.io.parse_single_example`.

We have to declare our data fields as usual (`example_reading_spec`) which we then can use to decode an example:

```py
def example_reading_spec():

    data_fields = {
        'inputs': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'targets': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    }

    return data_fields

def decode_example(serialized_example):
    """Return a dict of Tensors from a serialized tensorflow.Example."""
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features=example_reading_spec()
    )
```

Now we can use `Dataset.map` to load our dataset shards like this:

```py
record_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, buffer_size=1024)
record_dataset = record_dataset.map(decode_example)
```